# replace many different types of strings in hundres of files

Tags: perl, sed

I have about 50 different types of strings to search and replace in hundreds of files under the same folder.  I'd like to put the strings-to-be replaced in a `inputs.txt` file and then use `find` and `sed` commands to replace each input string with a "_modify" in lots of files.

Here is a quick example of what I want to do:

1) Strings to be searched saved in inputs.dat:

```
  string1
  string2
  string3

  string50
```

2)test1.txt and test2.txt are idential for now
      here is the string1
      here is the string2
      here is something else
      this is the string3
      this is the string50

3) I tried to chain all the sed command together to replace all strings recursively like below but it's quite alot of work if the strings become huge. I think a perl+sed should work but I don't know yet how to put them together.
    $find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/^string1$/strng1_modify/g'

3) I tried the sed script suggested below and got some error running in bash.  It looks like sed had issue with processing multiple lines.
$sed_program=$( sed 's#.+#s/&/\&_modify/g#' inputs.dat)

$find . -type f -print | xargs -0 sed -i "$sed_program"

error mesage: "$sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: Show what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: do you know that you can chain together sub cmds in sed like `sed 's/a/b/g;s/d/e/;.....;' file`? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the inputs file and turn it into a sed script:

Assuming your shell is bash/ksh/zsh, you can do:

```
sed_program=$( sed 's#.+#s/&/\&_modify/g#' inputs.txt )
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "$sed_program"
```